# How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I have a code that works only in IE anb I was looking for something similar in FF and Chrome to set user's default homepage through a link 'click here to make this site your default homepage', but so far I didn't find anything.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The question was voted down to -1. I voted it up again because it's a perfectly good question to ask, even if one does not agree with what the op is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Good question, I need it in a web application...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do it in FF because of security.  Check out this [article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1279376.aspx).  Your user would have to change the signed.applets.codebase_principal_support setting to false.  Probably not something that is worth counting on.

Comment: then why Facebook can do that? I think I saw they did it before

Answer (score 19):

What you're asking for is generally considered very annoying page behavior and, therefore, isn't widely supported.

A better UX (User Experience) choice is to give a small set of "how-to" instructions on how the users can make your page their homepage in their respective browsers. Give the user the choice!

Comment: Especially because links that only work in a particular browser are annoying.

Answer (score 6):

I Have found one script which will work both ie & Mozila. But won't work in opera & chrome.

Write below function inside javascript tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setHomepage()
{
 if (document.all)
    {
        document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
  document.body.setHomePage('http://www.kerala.in');

    }
    else if (window.sidebar)
    {
    if(window.netscape)
    {
         try
   {  
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");  
         }  
         catch(e)  
         {  
            alert("this action was aviod by your browser，if you want to enable，please enter about:config in your address line,and change the value of signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true");  
         }
    } 
    var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components. interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
    prefs.setCharPref('browser.startup.homepage','http://www.kerala.in');
 }
}
</script>
```

---

then Call this function setHomepage()  on click of button.

Comment: And Opera? And Webkit/Chrome/Safari? It stays the same. Don't do this, enable your user so that he can do it himself.

Comment: Sorry if this sounded rude. I just saw, that this is your first answer. Don't let yourself get discouraged by someone like me ;-)

Comment: You can format text as code (for better readability) by indenting a row 4 spaces.

Comment: `if (document.all)` is very old check for IE

Answer (score 5):

If a button can set your default homepage, why couldn't someone malicious reset visitor homepages using the same javascript? This is why such a function does not exist on well behaved browsers.

Comment: Because even IE asks the user for confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I was forced to investigate this today. I thought I'd post an answer with clear information on the problem.

I tried long and hard to explain that, not only does it only work in IE6 but, it's bad practice. Once my manager found that Google [had the functionality working](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/services/hp/index.html) (visit it in IE) in all versions of IE, I was forced to find a solution.

So, while `document.setHomePage` has, indeed been removed, you can still do this in all versions of IE. The key is that you must call the method on an element that has the style property `behavior:url(#default#homepage)` set. The following link will work in IE if placed on your page. You will have to find other methods for other browsers. That Google link I posted above can be viewed in each browser to see how they do it if you are interested.

```
<a
    href="#"
    style="behavior: url(#default#homepage);"
    onclick="this.setHomePage('http://google.com');return false;">
        Make Google your Homepage!
</a>
```

It looks like IE7+ might require this to happen on a click even though. I couldn't get the code to run in console when I tried.

Here's the MSDN page on the behavior. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms531418(v=vs.85).aspx

Now to go hang my head in shame.

Answer (score 2):

Use to be possible with this lovely snippet.

```
document.setHomePage("http://www.mywebsite.com/");
```

Shockingly, it was only supported by IE, and in IE7 it was discontinued.

This [article](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/sethomepage.html) says the best option is just to give succinct instructions on how to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately I was forced to investigate this today. This functionality exists in IE9, so it is likely that it can be relied on. You must, however, call `setHomePage` on the element which has the behavior style property set to `url(#default#homepage)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function addBookmarkForBrowser() {    
   if (document.all) {    
      window.external.AddFavorite(document.location.href , document.title);
   } else {    
      var ea = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");    
      ea.initMouseEvent("mousedown",1,1,window,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,null);    
      var eb = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];    
      eb.ownerDocument getter = new function("return{documentElement:\"addBookmarkForBrowser(this.docShell);\",getBoxObjectFor:eval}");    
      eb.dispatchEvent(ea);
   }    
}
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:addBookmarkForBrowser();">Add to Favorites</a>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Chrome for this line: "eb.ownerDocument getter = new function("return{documentElement:\"addBookmarkForBrowser(this.docShell);\",getBoxObjectFor:eval}"); "