# universal javascript for set homepage functionality

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any javascript that works on almost all browsers for setting a webpage as homepage?

I am using below one. But it only works for i.e. and mozilla

```
    var flag = false;
    function setHomepage(web)
    {
        if (document.all)
        {
            document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
            document.body.setHomePage(web);

        }
        else if (window.sidebar)
        {
            if(window.netscape)
            {
                try
                {  
                    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
                    flag = true;  
                }  
                catch(e)  
                {  
                    alert("This action was aviod by your browser. If you want to enable please enter about:config in your address line,and change the value of signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true");
                }
            } 
            if(flag)
            {
                var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components. interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
                prefs.setCharPref('browser.startup.homepage',web);
            }      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an earlier discussion thread on the subject: [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Basically, there's no universal support and changing the homepage is generally considered a very annoying thing to do.