# How to set my website as homepage for browsers by html code

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want to make a hyperlink for my website to set the browser homepage... someone told me the following code is useful, but it didn't work for me:

```
<a HREF onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.example.com');">
    <img src="house.gif">
    Click here to make us your Home Page
</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [universal javascript for set homepage functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075409/universal-javascript-for-set-homepage-functionality)

Comment: This isn't something that is supported now by most of the browsers, i think only IE can do this, and I'm not sure if it is still functional.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Comment: Changing the homepage is generally considered a very annoying thing to do

Comment: Don't do that. It's really annoying and nobody will use it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with modern browsers, as it is considered as great security risk. `setHomePage()` javascript function have been removed few years ago.

Consider the case, that you click on some link, and it sets your homepage to some fake google page (for example one L is 1). Every time you think you are using a google, you may get some prepared results, in the best case - made to earn money from ads. But it may be much worse, a fake mail or bank site... or simply some porn site. Doesn't matter. It is dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the small image to be on your website use this html code and where it says
http://example.com  <-- You need to use your website here

```
<a HREF onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.example.com');">
    Make as homepage
</a>
```