# Set browser as my website as homepage for Firefox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

I have to set my web page as homepage in Firefox using JavaScript. I used an script:

```
    onclick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
this.setHomePage('http://www.example.com.html');"
```

It works in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to set a users homepage with Javascript, due to some obvious security reasons.