# Is it possible to set a website as homepage in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, browser

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [set browser as my website as homepage for firefox using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116513/set-browser-as-my-website-as-homepage-for-firefox-using-javascript)
>   [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

I knew how to set homepage from a website in Internet Explorer using JavaScript; however, due to a security issue I can't do it in Mozilla.

Is there a way to set it in Mozilla using JavaScript?

Comment: dup :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116513/set-browser-as-my-website-as-homepage-for-firefox-using-javascript

Comment: See [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Comment: I do not want your app to set my homepage. I have set my homepage(s) myself. If I want your website as my homepage, I will add it myself. If you reset my homepage without asking, your app and website will immediately be added to my 'intrusive - do not use' list. If your app asks me if I want to change my homepage, it will be added to my 'annoying - do not use' list.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible.

(Hooray!)

Answer (score 4):

Ask politelly to the user to do it.

If the user consider it's worthy he/she will.

Comment: Or … don't. If the user wants to set it as their homepage, they can do it (hopefully). Even polite requests come off sounding as needy begging for traffic.

Comment: `<evil>` Or promise the user dancing pigs if they do it.`</evil>` After all, "Given a choice between dancing pigs and security, users will pick dancing pigs every time." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_pigs