# "Make this page your Startpage" script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have Googled for a JavaScript that sets the current page to your startpage. 
But all I can find is some old script for IE 5 and up.

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Make This Site Your Home Page" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('Page URL beginning with http:// here');">
</FORM>
```

They only seem to work in IE and they also seem to be inline.

I'd like one in my script file and one that works in all browsers.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is such a script that works in all browsers.  People don't like their homepage being reset, and if it were possible with Javascript, it would be exploited and abused.

Comment: Most browsers consider this to be a security threat. Because you could set their browser's home page to a phishing site.

Comment: Thanks. That totally makes sense. Guess I won't find one hey..

Comment: If enduser likes the site s/he will make it homepage anyway. Pushing it to the user's throat will likely only scare them and never come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Id like one in my script file

That shouldn't be a problem. Add

```
document.getElementById("link_id").style.behavior = .......
```

to your script file (also giving the link an ID).

> and one that works in all browsers.

That is not possible. (Thankfully, in my opinion.) I *think* there was a workaround for Firefox, but none for the other browsers.

Comment: Thats what I thought.
Thanks for that.
Time to tell my client it's not gonna happen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**The answers given in this duplicate post cover it best:**

[How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

**In essence:** Just don't.

**If you feel you have to:** provide instructions, enable users to do it manually.