# how can i set the default homepage "in the browser" from my c++ application?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

how can i set the default homepage (in Firefox, Google chrome, ....)  from my c++ application
like a user clicked a button on my application the homepage changing automatically.

any helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074063/how-set-a-website-as-homepage-in-ie-firefox-chrome-and-safari-with-c

Try this.

Answer (score 3):

It's different for each browser.  For example, [this is how to do it in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043616/programmatically-set-the-default-homepage-for-mozilla-firefox) (in C#, but that's not really the point).

It would be far easier to ask users to do this on a thank-you web page after they download your program.  They're already in the browser they normally use.