# Is there a javascript function which can prompt the user to set the current page as homepage?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Is there a javascript function which can prompt the user to set the current page as homepage?

I need something that works on modern browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript

Comment: This is so 90's. Plus annoying website behavior.

Comment: What, your product not good enough for someone to want to set this as their home page on their own?

Comment: "I bet someone got a really nice bonus for that feature" - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is the `setHomePage` function that is IE specific.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124001/are-there-any-alternative-to-sethomepage-function) SO thread for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Make This Site Your Home Page" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('Page URL beginning with http:// here');">
```