# asp.net function to make my website as default page

Tags: asp.net

hHi,

simple and fast question:

How do I make a link in which the user will be asked if my homepage should be his defualt page in his web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, unless you are using IE.

For IE the link would look like this:

```
<a target="_self" href="#" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
                   this.setHomePage('http://www.yoursite.com');">Set Homepage</a>
```

User interaction is required for this (i.e going into the browser settings and intentionally setting it), and a good thing too, otherwise any link could reset my homepage.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946189/1583) SO question and answers.

Comment: Of course userinteraction is requiered but a lot of pages have this like "Do you really want to set this page as default page"

Comment: @Kovu - many sites these days will explain how to set the home page through browser settings. They do not have such links.

Comment: Don't agree, I know hundret of german sites who have this links.

Comment: @Kovu - for anything other than IE?

Comment: Nope, but that was not my question, was it?

Comment: @Kovu - And my answer stands. You can only do that in IE.

Comment: It's okay for me, to do it only there, thank you. I added a If-else for other browser then IE and tell me user with an alarm to set this for himself :) You get a +

Answer (score 0):

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
                                document.write('&lt;a href="javascript:history.go(0);" onClick="this.style.behavior=\'url(#default#homepage)\';this.setHomePage(\'http://mysite.com\');"&gt;');
                                document.write('&lt;strong&gt;Click Here to make this your homepage&lt;/strong&gt;');
                            </script>
```

As Oded mentions, this is "IE-specific".