# Make default homepage for IE9 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a default homepage script using the famous script for IE but I'm trying to add it in a jquery function.

So this works:

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
  document.body.setHomePage('http://www.google.com');">
    Click here to make My Site your default homepage
  </a>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<a href="#" onClick="">
    Click here to make My Site your default homepage
  </a>

$('a').click(function() {

 document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
  document.body.setHomePage('http://www.google.com');

});
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

EDIT: **Please note the on click function doesnt work for IE9.** IE6,7 and 8 it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery 1.7 use the `.on()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").on("click", function(event){
       document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
       document.body.setHomePage('http://www.google.com');

    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nKkNV/

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in IE (tested in IE 7). Check [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7ZvY/2/) here.

But it seems like you cannot do the same in FF. Read about it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

Alternatively, you can provide an instruction in FF on how to change.. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/C7ZvY/) here

Comment: IE9, doesnt work sir. I am not interested IE6 and 7. Thank you. I was aware of that and I should point it.

Comment: Maybe (hopefully) they completely removed this anti-feature in IE9... in this case it wouldn't be possible anymore at all.

Answer (score 0):

By using this: $('a') you are targeting all links on the page.

Try giving the anchor tag an id attribute, then change your jQuery selector to look for that attribute, like this (also remove the onClick attribute altogether):

```
<a href="#" id="makeDefault">
    Click here to make My Site your default homepage
  </a>

$('a#makeDefault').click(function() {
  document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
  document.body.setHomePage('http://www.google.com');
});
```

Comment: has not difference. Tried it. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

One thing you are doing wrong in both versions is that you have a link with link text “Click here to make My Site your default homepage” that points to the start of the current page.

Comment: What you talking about? It doesnt affect the code in ANY way.

Comment: It is what the markup means. Whatever might happen when JavaScript is enabled is a different issue.