# Create a button that can add website to homescreen

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm hoping there's a way of doing this, I'm sure I've seen it done before but can't for the life of me remember where!

When a user visits a site via a mobile device, I want to create a button that says something like <kbd>install</kbd> or <kbd>add to homescreen</kbd>, once they click this button, the website is added to their homescreen, as it would be if they were to do it themselves using the menu.

Is this possible? Googling around it's unclear if people have managed to accomplish this or not.

Answer (score 0):

http://cubiq.org is what I used, but it only works for iDevices. Works really well

Comment: Thanks. This is just a pop-up that explains it though, right? There's no way of automating the process via a single button?

Comment: Its a good idea and one that I did explore a while back but obviously didn't get the answer

Answer (score -1):

You should better have a look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript).
The answers on this question discuss how it is achieved in browsers using javascript.
The technique described used to work for IE (some previous versions) and with little hack around for Mozilla and does not support for Chrome or Safari.

But the main thing most people say is that you should not do it. And I expect the same. I dont like someone doing something for me without asking me or telling me what to do.

Comment: The link is not for mobile - and OP is asking how to install using a button, not how to do it automatically (I will edit his question to remove that word)

Comment: I think my question might have been a little miss-understood. I wanted to save my website to the homescreen of a smart phone. Not make it the default home-page.