# Make html file homepage of a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, html

### Explanation

I have a `HTML` page and it contains the basic features which any home page or new tab page should have. It contains basic `HTML` and some `CSS` and `Javascript` commands.

I use Google Chrome and I want to set my webpage as the new tab page, or alternatively, I can set it as the homepage and open my page on start-up!

Is there code in any language which I can use to set it as my homepage. `HTML` and `Javascript` are preferred by me.

### Example Code

```
<html>
<title> New Tab </title>
<!---The code for making homepage or start-up page --->
<!---Other statements --->
</html>
```

Comment: A bit unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to [set your homepage in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, how to change homepage, but that homepage should be my html page, which is not published and is accessible just to me!

Comment: So just set it to a local file URL, i.e. `file:///home/whatever/home.html`

Comment: You can check the `Joby Mavelikara's` answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript. That too it can work for `IE`, `Firefox` and not for `Opera` and `Chrome`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google chrome click on the top-right menu icon and select settings. Now under appearance check **Show Home button** option. Now click on the change link under it. Here you can select a url of the home page for your chrome browser.

Comment: @KashishArora try pasting that URL like `file://whatever-path-you-see-in-your-browser-when-viewing-your-local-html-file`

Comment: @KashishArora then upload it whats the problem

Comment: It's free to upload your page or send me I'll upload it for you.

Comment: yes I mean whats bad in uploading that page to a live server???

Comment: @KashishArora I just tried setting my home page to a local file page in Chrome. Works just fine.

Comment: Umm.. actually, that worked! What the problem was, I wrote just the simple address, but chrome on opening showed `file:\` and then the address, this worked! Feeling sorry for myself! Thanks, anyway!