# How to hidden install extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, browser-extension, crossrider

Is there a way to install a crossrider extension on a user's computer without letting him/her know it? My website requires this when a user click on a "set as homepage" link.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we shouldn't help programmers creating malware or installing things without user permission and hiding them.

Comment: What's the url, so I can never go there.

Comment: Hello, my intention is not to create malware it only brings my page on next browser session when user asks to set it as homepage. Is there a better way to do so then please let me know I will be thankful

Comment: If you're installing something on the user's computer, they should be ***very*** aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the user's home page is generaly concidered as a very annoying thing to do. You can look at [this previous discution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript).

Installing an extension without warning the user is not possible in a normal way because of obvious security reasons. When you know what kind of things you can do with google extension, it's better like this. It should be a huge problem if an extension can install himself without warn and send your password or personnal information like your bank credentials...